# Python Pypdf2 pdf merger, choose directory manually when saving

Tags: python, path, pypdf

I am trying to merge multiple pdfs and save to a folder. How can I make it allow user to choose manually which directory to save?

```
import os.path
from os import path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

pdfs = ['text1.pdf', 'text2.pdf', 'text3.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    if path.exists(pdf) == True:
        merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: You can use input (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) or pass it as an argument to your function using argv (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

Comment: I use this code along with PyQt5 code to make a report (pdf) page. I was thinking to save the resulting pdf file similar to "save as" option say in MS Word. So  it directs you to a default folder (say Downloads) from where you can navigate to any folder. Looks like it is not as simple as I have imagined.

Comment: With pyqt I think you should use a FileDialog to navigate to the folders.

Comment: @daniboy000 could you show me how to do it by adding a few lines in above code?

Comment: It's been a while since I've developed with pyqt, but you can check this link for some examples. http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/dialogs/